# How to split character value properly

Tags: r

I have a data frame which consists of some composite information. I would like to split the vector a into the vectors "a" and "d", where "a" corresponds only to the numeric ID 898, 3467 ,234 ,222 and vector "d" contains the corresponding character values.

Data:

```
a<-c("898_Me","3467_You or ", "234_Hi-hi", "222_what")
b<-c(1,8,3,8)
c<-c(2,4,6,2)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

What I tried so far:

```
a<-str(df$a)

a<-strsplit(df$a, split)
```

But that just doesn't work out with my regular expression skills.

The required output table might have the form:

```
                       a    d        b   c
                      898   Me       1   2
                      3467  You or   8   3
                      234   Hi-hi    3   6
                      222   what     8   2
```

Comment: What is `a<-str(df$a)` meant to achieve? Also what is `split` and what regular expression have you tried? Is all you trying to do is to split by `_` (like in the answer below)? What regular expression except `_` is needed in order to achieve that?

Comment: I just would like to separate the numeric id from the string and achieve that within a data frame.

Comment: Do you always have `_` between the numbers and strings?

Comment: Yes thats always the case

Comment: and does the non-numeric information never contain a `_` of its own? (`_`  is not `-`)

Comment: No sometimes `123_Hi-Hi` but always  `_` between numeric id and string. My data frame is quite large, therefore an illustration of that procedure on a data frame would be great.Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

a<-c("898_Me","3467_You or ", "234_Hi-hi", "222_what")

b<-c(1,8,3,8)

c<-c(2,4,6,2)

df <-data.frame(a,b,c)

final_df <- separate(df , a , c("a" , "d") , sep = "_")

#    a       d b c
#1  898      Me 1 2
#2 3467 You or  8 4
#3  234   Hi-hi 3 6
#4  222    what 8 2

final_df$d

# [1] "Me"      "You or " "Hi-hi"   "what"
```

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` is right, but you need to pass the character to split with:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$a), "_"))
#      [,1]   [,2]     
# [1,] "898"  "Me"     
# [2,] "3467" "You or "
# [3,] "234"  "Hi-hi"  
# [4,] "222"  "what"
```

Or

```
library(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(df$a, "_", simplify = TRUE)
```

Comment: May I ask you to illustrate your answer on the data frame? I just cant do it: `split <- strsplit(df$a, "_")`      Error in `strsplit (df$a, "_")` : non-character argument

Comment: `strsplit(as.character(df$a), "_")`. The error message there for a reason.

Comment: Their example code will make "df$a" a factor, rather than character. Also worth pointing out to the OP that the number this gives will be a character rather than numeric class.

Answer (score 0):

With your example, Here is my solution in base R:

```
df$a2 <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", a)
df$d <- gsub("[0-9]", "", a)
```

That gives:

```
> df
             a b c   a2        d
1       898_Me 1 2  898      _Me
2 3467_You or  8 4 3467 _You or 
3    234_Hi-hi 3 6  234   _Hi-hi
4     222_what 8 2  222    _what
```

Not elegant but it preserves original data and easy to apply.

Comment: You could also do `extract(df, a, c("d", "e"), "(\\d+)(\\D+)", remove = FALSE)` in order to achieve the same in one line, though I don't think anything else needed here rather than to split by `_`

Comment: Thank you @DavidArenburg for you suggestion. I did not know the `extract` function. Which package it belong to?